# NameError on a function while calling for it in another function of a class

Tags: python-3.x, nameerror

I developed some code for [a problem on leetcode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/). There was a class and a function and I added another function `matchingBrackets`. Yet, when I make the code run I have a NameError on this function. Indeed, it seems it is not defined.

```
class Solution:

    def matchingBrackets(self, s:str) -> bool:
        lefts = ['(','{','[']
        rights = [')',']','}']
        if s[0] in lefts:
            function(s[1:],type)
        elif s[0] in rights:
            if s[0] == bracket:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            print("different from brackets")
            s = s[1:]

    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:

        return matchingBrackets(s[1:],bracket)
```

When running it the code on leetcode console, it returns:

```
NameError: name 'matchingBrackets' is not defined
Line 19 in isValid (Solution.py)
Line 30 in __helper__ (Solution.py)
Line 44 in _driver (Solution.py)
Line 55 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues.

When you are referring to methods defined in the same class as `def method(self, arg1, arg2):`, you need to further use that method as `self.method(arg1, arg2)` if you are using it from the same class. That is, your `isValid` method needs to return `self.matchingBrackets(s[1:],bracket)` instead.

Also, you define `matchingBrackets` as a method taking only one argument apart from `self`, but then you pass to it two arguments `s[1:]` and `bracket`. This is also why it is not clear what the variable `bracket` is referring to.

Also, I don't really understand what `function(s[1:],type)` is referring to. Did it define it outside the snippet of the code that you posted?

Finally, I am not sure that the logic of the function does what the Leetcode question is asking.